# how to handle partial view elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview, textchanged

please refer this code and it is for a partial view of my web application developed using mvc.

```
@model PortalModels.WholeSaleModelUser
    @using (Html.BeginForm("uploadFile", "WholeSaleTrade", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>WholeSaleModelUser</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
        <div id="partial">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img id="blah" src="../../Images/no_image.jpg" alt="your image" height="200px" width="170px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadUserImage() {
            var userImg = document.getElementById("blah");
            var imgNm = $("#Name").value;
            userImg.src = "D:/FEISPortal/FortalApplication/Img/" + imgNm + ".png";
            alert(imgNm);
            alert(userImg.src);
        }
    </script>
```

i need to handle the **textchange** event of this textbox in partial view using javascript code i have mentioned above

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
```

please somebody tell me how to handle the text change event of the above code line of textbox..

Answer (score 0):

```
$document.on('blur', 'TextBox', function(){
    //Do something
});
```

This format should work for any fields on a partial view.  from here http://api.jquery.com/on/